# Display the Urban Airship Landing Page when the corresponding push notification is received while the app is not showing a content

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, urbanairship.com

By using the landing page action I am able to send the push message in foreground or background state and as mentioned in doc, the message is showing when the user is opening the app for the next time.

But I want to directly display the landing page container (without showing a In-app notification and to wait for user interaction to display it) when the app received it in foreground state and immediately (not to wait until the next launch).

In the docs it is mentioned that:

> If you need to display a Landing Page while the app is in the
>   foreground state, replace the registry predicate associated with that
>   action with one that allows foreground execution.

How to retrieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You can update the predicate with:

```
[[UAirship shared].actionRegistry updatePredicate:nil
                                 forEntryWithName:kUALandingPageActionDefaultRegistryName];
```

Comment: I have try it, but it is not working. How to use it.